# Problem with web scraping of required content from a URL link in R

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I am using a script to scrape the required content from a link in which there are different subjects.

```
library(rvest)
url   <- "https://ssb.bannerprod.memphis.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec"

query <- list(term_in = "202110", sel_subj = "dummy", sel_day = "dummy",
              sel_schd = "dummy", sel_insm = "dummy", sel_camp = "dummy",
              sel_levl = "dummy", sel_sess = "dummy", sel_instr = "dummy",
              sel_ptrm = "dummy", sel_attr = "dummy", sel_subj = "ARCH",
              sel_crse = "",      sel_title = "",     sel_insm = "%",
              sel_from_cred = "", sel_to_cred = "",   sel_camp = "%",
              sel_levl = "%",     sel_ptrm = "%",     sel_instr = "%",
              sel_attr = "%",     begin_hh =  "0",    begin_mi = "0",
              begin_ap = "a",     end_hh = "0",       end_mi = "0",
              end_ap = "a")
```

In the above query `sel_subj` changes for every different subjects

```
html <- read_html(httr::POST(url, body = query))
classes <- html %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//th/a") %>% html_text()
instructor_nodes <- html %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "//td[@class='dddefault']/a[contains(@href, 'mailto')]")

instructors <- html_attr(instructor_nodes, "target") 
emails <- html_attr(instructor_nodes, "href")

length(classes)
[1] 32
length(instructors)
[1] 39
length(emails)
[1] 39

sq <- seq(max(length(classes), length(instructors), length(emails)))
data.frame(classes[sq], instructors[sq], emails[sq])
```

And the result looks like below which is wrong:

```
                                                classes.sq.      instructors.sq.                  emails.sq.
1   Fundamentals of Design Studio - 23838 - ARCH 1111 - 001 Jennifer L. Thompson mailto:jlthmps5@memphis.edu
2   Fundamentals of Design Studio - 23839 - ARCH 1111 - 002     Pamela J. Hurley mailto:pjhurley@memphis.edu
3            Design Visualization - 11107 - ARCH 1113 - 001 Michael K. Chisamore mailto:mkchsmre@memphis.edu
4            Design Visualization - 18386 - ARCH 1113 - 002 Michael K. Chisamore mailto:mkchsmre@memphis.edu
5       History of Architecture 1 - 23218 - ARCH 1211 - 001     Pamela J. Hurley mailto:pjhurley@memphis.edu
6           Building Technology 2 - 23840 - ARCH 2412 - 001     Marika E. Snider mailto:mesnider@memphis.edu
7       Computer Apps in Design 2 - 11111 - ARCH 2612 - 001   Timothy E. Michael mailto:tmichael@memphis.edu
8                 Design Studio 2 - 11112 - ARCH 2712 - 001   Timothy E. Michael mailto:tmichael@memphis.edu
9                 Design Studio 2 - 15408 - ARCH 2712 - 002      Andrew M. Parks  mailto:amparks@memphis.edu
10  Survey of Interiors+Furniture - 25734 - ARCH 3213 - 001      Andrew M. Parks  mailto:amparks@memphis.edu
11  Determinants of Modern Design - 27436 - ARCH 3221 - 001     Michael D. Hagge  mailto:mdhagge@memphis.edu
12            Structural Design 2 - 23837 - ARCH 3322 - 001     Michael D. Hagge  mailto:mdhagge@memphis.edu
13          Professional Practice - 25097 - ARCH 3431 - 001      Andrew M. Parks  mailto:amparks@memphis.edu
14                Design Studio 4 - 11115 - ARCH 3714 - 001         Sonia Raheel  mailto:sraheel@memphis.edu
15                Design Studio 4 - 23221 - ARCH 3714 - 002     Pamela J. Hurley mailto:pjhurley@memphis.edu
16 Architecture Independent Study - 11117 - ARCH 4021 - 201   Jennifer L. Barker mailto:jlbrker1@memphis.edu
17             Sustainable Design - 19491 - ARCH 4421 - 001   Jennifer L. Barker mailto:jlbrker1@memphis.edu
18     Internship in Architecture - 21000 - ARCH 4430 - 001     Marika E. Snider mailto:mesnider@memphis.edu
19                Design Studio 6 - 11134 - ARCH 4716 - 001     Pamela J. Hurley mailto:pjhurley@memphis.edu
20             Sustainable Design - 19492 - ARCH 6421 - 001     Marika E. Snider mailto:mesnider@memphis.edu
21      Advanced Design Seminar 2 - 18387 - ARCH 7012 - 001     Marika E. Snider mailto:mesnider@memphis.edu
22    Contemporary Architecture 2 - 24104 - ARCH 7222 - 001     Pamela J. Hurley mailto:pjhurley@memphis.edu
23     Internship in Architecture - 19495 - ARCH 7430 - 001   Jennifer L. Barker mailto:jlbrker1@memphis.edu
24      Adv Professional Practice - 19496 - ARCH 7431 - 001 Jennifer L. Thompson mailto:jlthmps5@memphis.edu
25       Advanced Design Studio 2 - 18389 - ARCH 7712 - 001     Michael D. Hagge  mailto:mdhagge@memphis.edu
26          Architecture Research - 25098 - ARCH 7930 - 001     Brian D. Andrews mailto:bdndrews@memphis.edu
27     Architecture Thesis Studio - 19499 - ARCH 7996 - 003 Jennifer L. Thompson mailto:jlthmps5@memphis.edu
28     Architecture Thesis Studio - 19500 - ARCH 7996 - 004     Brian D. Andrews mailto:bdndrews@memphis.edu
29     Architecture Thesis Studio - 19501 - ARCH 7996 - 005      Andrew M. Parks  mailto:amparks@memphis.edu
30     Architecture Thesis Studio - 19502 - ARCH 7996 - 006     Michael D. Hagge  mailto:mdhagge@memphis.edu
31     Architecture Thesis Studio - 19503 - ARCH 7996 - 007     Brian D. Andrews mailto:bdndrews@memphis.edu
32     Architecture Thesis Studio - 20972 - ARCH 7996 - 008 Michael K. Chisamore mailto:mkchsmre@memphis.edu
33                                                     <NA>     Pamela J. Hurley mailto:pjhurley@memphis.edu
34                                                     <NA>   Jennifer L. Barker mailto:jlbrker1@memphis.edu
35                                                     <NA> Michael K. Chisamore mailto:mkchsmre@memphis.edu
36                                                     <NA>     Pamela J. Hurley mailto:pjhurley@memphis.edu
37                                                     <NA> Jennifer L. Thompson mailto:jlthmps5@memphis.edu
38                                                     <NA>     Brian D. Andrews mailto:bdndrews@memphis.edu
39                                                     <NA>     Marika E. Snider mailto:mesnider@memphis.edu
```

But in the link, the data looks different.
For example:
There are few classes `without any instructor and email` (It is mentioned `TBA`) like below:

[image]

And there are few other classes that have `two/three/four/multiple instructors`.

[image]

And there are few other classes with the `same instructor given multiple times` like below:

[image]

For such data I want my output to be looked like below:

```
                                                classes.sq.      instructors.sq.                  emails.sq.
1   Fundamentals of Design Studio - 23838 - ARCH 1111 - 001 Jennifer L. Thompson mailto:jlthmps5@memphis.edu
2   Fundamentals of Design Studio - 23839 - ARCH 1111 - 002          TBA         
3            Design Visualization - 11107 - ARCH 1113 - 001 Michael K. Chisamore,Pamela J. Hurley mailto:mkchsmre@memphis.edu,pjhurley@memphis.edu
4            Design Visualization - 18386 - ARCH 1113 - 002 Pamela J. Hurley,Michael K. Chisamore mailto:pjhurley@memphis.edu,mkchsmre@memphis.edu
5       History of Architecture 1 - 23218 - ARCH 1211 - 001     Marika E. Snider mailto:mesnider@memphis.edu
6           Building Technology 2 - 23840 - ARCH 2412 - 001     Timothy E. Michael mailto:tmichael@memphis.edu
```

P.S. if the posted URL link doesn't work. Please follow this:

```
In this link `https://ssb.bannerprod.memphis.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched` 
Select by term -> Spring Term 2021 (view only) -> Submit
Subject -> select ARCH Architecture -> scroll down and click Class Search
```

How to deal with missing data (TBA), multiple instructors, and the same instructor given multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with using the `html_nodes()` function.  This function will return a list of values without any regard to which node the value was found.  Since you webpage will have sometime have multiple instructors per class or none, a more targeted approach is needed.

In this code block we first find each of the class nodes which contain all of the information we want.  Then we parse each of those node individually (inside the `lapply` function) to extract the instructors and email also checking for empty fields.  There is a single line in each data frame for each instructor, so some data frame will have multiple lines if there are multiple instructors.

We assemble a list of data frames (`bind_rows`) for each class and then merge the instructor and email results for the same class

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url   <- "https://ssb.bannerprod.memphis.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec"

query <- list(term_in = "202110", sel_subj = "dummy", sel_day = "dummy",
              sel_schd = "dummy", sel_insm = "dummy", sel_camp = "dummy",
              sel_levl = "dummy", sel_sess = "dummy", sel_instr = "dummy",
              sel_ptrm = "dummy", sel_attr = "dummy", sel_subj = "ARCH",
              sel_crse = "",      sel_title = "",     sel_insm = "%",
              sel_from_cred = "", sel_to_cred = "",   sel_camp = "%",
              sel_levl = "%",     sel_ptrm = "%",     sel_instr = "%",
              sel_attr = "%",     begin_hh =  "0",    begin_mi = "0",
              begin_ap = "a",     end_hh = "0",       end_mi = "0",
              end_ap = "a")

html <- read_html(httr::POST(url, body = query))
classes <- html %>% html_nodes("th.ddtitle") %>% html_text()

classinfo <- html %>% html_nodes("tr td.dddefault")
classinfo <- html %>% html_nodes(xpath = ".//tr/td[@class='dddefault']") 
classinfo <- classinfo[nchar( html_text(classinfo))>50 ]   #eliminate the extra found nodes

classlink <- classinfo %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")  #find all links
classlinktext <- classinfo %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_text()    #find the link text
classlink <- classlink[classlinktext=="View Catalog Entry"]       #keep only the links for "View Catalog Entry"

dfs <-lapply(1:length(classinfo), function(i) {
 # classname <-classes[i] %>% html_node(xpath = ".//a") %>% html_text()
  instructor_node <- classinfo[i] %>% html_nodes("table.datadisplaytable") %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = ".//a[contains(@href, 'mailto')]")
  
  instructors <- html_attr(instructor_node, "target") 
  emails <- html_attr(instructor_node, "href")
  #check to see if instructor was assign if not TBD
  if(length(instructors)==0){
    instructors <- "TBD"
    emails <- "NA"
  }
  data.frame(classname=classes[i], link=classlink[i], instructors, emails)
})
   
#merge list into data frame
answer<- bind_rows(dfs)

#consolidation the instructions in the same class
finalanswer<-answer %>% group_by(classes) %>% summarize(instructors2 = paste(instructors, collapse = ", "), emails = paste(emails, collapse = ", "))
# the paste(instructors, collapse = ", ") could be contained within the lapply 
# loop but adding it here add some flexibility depending on whether
# answer or final answer is the end result.
head(finalanswer, 16)
tail(finalanswer, 16)
```

Comment: Small help, please. When I used `sel_subj = "ART"` in the code for `query` I see an Error. `Error in xml_nodeset(NextMethod()) : Expecting an external pointer: [type=NULL]` Could you please tell me how to solve this issue. thanq

Comment: The error because the vector index is greater than the number of elements in the vector.  If you look there are 120 classes but only 119 MeetingTimeNodes.  The last class is for a thesis and does not have a meeting time.  The quick and dirty fix is to change the `lapply` to `1:length(MeetingTimeNodes)` the other is find the class name within the lapply loop, but that will take more time to figure out.

Comment: Yes, thanq. I figured out that one class and removed it from `classes` I got the clear output now.

Comment: When I click each class in present in each subject, I see one attribute `capacity` which shows the number. How to extract that for each subject? Any help please.

Comment: I made a few edits.  To handle where the class information didn't have the schedule meeting time as in the previous comments.  Also I extracted out the link to each class additional information.  You will now need to write a loop to reach each class' link and extract out the capacity.  If you are having trouble with that, I suggest creating a new question.  These comments are diverging from the intent of the original question.

Comment: As you said I created a new question to get the `capacity (seats)` for all the classes of the subject. Please check this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64545146/how-to-loop-to-reach-each-class-link-and-extract-out-the-attribute-capacity-seat`