# How to loop to reach each class link and extract out the attribute capacity seats in R

Tags: html, r, url, web-scraping, rvest

I actually wanted to extract the `capacity (seats)` attribute for each `class` present in this link. This is the actual link `https://ssb.bannerprod.memphis.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec`

If the posted link doesn't work: Please do this

```
In this link `https://ssb.bannerprod.memphis.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched` 
Select by term -> Spring Term 2021 (view only) -> Submit
Subject -> select ARCH Architecture -> scroll down and click Class Search
```

For example:

For the subject `ARCH`, the classes look like below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The above pictures are only a few classes of subject `ARCH`. Still, there are many classes. If you click each class you will see the attribute `capacity` which shows the `seats` number.

I want the output to be looked like below:

```
classes                                                          capacity - seats
Fundamentals of Design Studio - 23839 - ARCH 1111 - 002             15
Design Visualization - 11107 - ARCH 1113 - 001                      15
Building Technology 2 - 23840 - ARCH 2412 - 001                     20
```

How to make a loop in `R` to get the `capacity (seats)` attribute for each `class` of each `subject`.

P.S. This question is a continuation of my previous post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64515601/problem-with-web-scraping-of-required-content-from-a-url-link-in-r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is very similar to the previous solution.
It is more straight forward since the link to the class size is in the same node as the class title.  Depending on what information you what the class size table will need to be cleaned up before merging with the remaining data.

Also since one will be querying multiple pages on the site, please introduce a slight system pause to be polite and to avoid appearing like a hacker.
Note there is no error checking to ensure the correct table is available, I suggest you consider this before making this production code.

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64515601/problem-with-web-scraping-of-required-content-from-a-url-link-in-r/64517844#64517844
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

# In this link `https://ssb.bannerprod.memphis.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched` 
# Select by term -> Spring Term 2021 (view only) -> Submit
# Subject -> select ARCH Architecture -> scroll down and click Class Search

url   <- "https://ssb.bannerprod.memphis.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec"
query <- list(term_in = "202110", sel_subj = "dummy", sel_day = "dummy",
              sel_schd = "dummy", sel_insm = "dummy", sel_camp = "dummy",
              sel_levl = "dummy", sel_sess = "dummy", sel_instr = "dummy",
              sel_ptrm = "dummy", sel_attr = "dummy", sel_subj = "ARCH",
              sel_crse = "",      sel_title = "",     sel_insm = "%",
              sel_from_cred = "", sel_to_cred = "",   sel_camp = "%",
              sel_levl = "%",     sel_ptrm = "%",     sel_instr = "%",
              sel_attr = "%",     begin_hh =  "0",    begin_mi = "0",
              begin_ap = "a",     end_hh = "0",       end_mi = "0",
              end_ap = "a")

html <- read_html(httr::POST(url, body = query))
classes <- html %>% html_nodes("th.ddtitle") 

dfs<-lapply(classes, function(class) {
   #get class name
   classname <-class %>% html_text()
   print(classname)
   #Pause in order not be a denial of service attach
   Sys.sleep(0.5)
   classlink <- class %>% html_node("a") %>% html_attr("href")
   fulllink <- paste0("https://ssb.bannerprod.memphis.edu", classlink)
   
   newpage <-read_html(fulllink)
   #find the tables 
   tables <- newpage %>% html_nodes("table.datadisplaytable") 
   #find the index to the correct table 
   seatingtable <- which(html_attr(tables, "summary") == "This layout table is used to present the seating numbers.")
   size <-tables[seatingtable] %>% html_table(header=TRUE)
   #may want to clean up table before combining in dataframe
   # i.e  size[[1]][1, -1]
   data.frame(class=classname, size[[1]], link=fulllink)
})

answer <- bind_rows(dfs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful.